# Unknown email code from CDO.Message send method

Tags: email, vbscript, asp-classic, cdo.message

I'm trying to send an email via vbscript.  Here's my email code:
I've hidden the email address of course.  In my actual code I'm using a valid email address.

```
Dim objCDO
Set objCDO = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.oa.caiso.com" 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Update 
objCDO.To = "abcemail@devnull.com"
objCDO.From = Sender
objCDO.cc = ""
objCDO.bcc = ""
objCDO.Subject = txtSubject
objCDO.HTMLBody = Replace(sBody, Chr(10),"<br>")
On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next
objCDO.Send
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    Response.Write "Just after the send command "
    Response.Write "Err.Number is " & Err.Number & "<br>"
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
set objCDO = nothing
```

When this code runs I see the following error:

Just after the send command Err.Number is -2147220978

Now, when I research this error number there is no reference anywhere for error code -2147220978  In fact, a Google search for the number -2147220978 returns no results at all.

Would you have any idea what that odd error code means?

Comment: Please confirm that you are using ASP Classic, not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4):

-2147220978 = 8004020E

From CDOSYSERR.h

```
//
// MessageId: CDO_E_SENDER_REJECTED
//
// MessageText:
//
// The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: %1
//
#define CDO_E_SENDER_REJECTED            0x8004020EL
```

**Decoding Errors**

-2147220978 style numbers are 32 bit signed integers, convert to hex with calculator.

Windows errors (smallish numbers) and  COM HResults (typically, but with exceptions, start with an 8 as in 0x80040154) are defined in WinError.h, except 8007nnnn where you look up the Window error number that it contains.

As a general rule Windows errors are less than 65,535 (0xFFFF). Errors starting 0x80000001 are Component Object Model (COM) HResults. Errors starting 0xc0000001 are NTStatus results.

NTStatus errors (typically but not always start with an C as in 0xC0000022) are defined in NTStatus.h.

.h files are the best source because it includes the symbolic name of the error which can give clues such as the source of the error. FormatMessage doesn't give the symbolic name only the description.

You get these files by downloading the Platform SDK (it's gigabytes)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx%3Fid%3D8279&sa=U&ei=w2IrULDDLsHFmAWbmIHoBg&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHZn9-4f2NnuN9o3UWUsOF3wL7HBQ

If you just want the two files I have them on my skydrive so I can reference them anywhere I go.
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA!121

Note internet errors (12,000 - 12,999) are windows errors but are specified in wininet.h also available above.

There are errors defined in other .h files. But 99% are in the three above.

**Structure of HResults and NTStatus Codes**

The most significant bit in HResults, and the two most significant bits in NTStatus are set on error. Hence Hresults start 8 on error and NTStatus starts C on Error. The next 14 or 15 bits are reserved and some specify the facility - what area the error is in. This is the third and fourth number when reading hex. EG 0xnn07nnnn - An HResult facility code 7 is a normal Windows' error (returned from a COM program - hence it's returned as a HResult). Facility codes are defined in Winerror.h for HResults and NTStatus.h for NTStatus codes. They are different.

**To Decode 0x8003nnnn Errors**

HResults with facility code 3 means the HResult contains OLE Structured Storage errors (0x0 to 0xff). These don't seem to be in Windows' header files and the list of codes is at the end of this post.

**To Decode 0x8004nnnn Errors**

HResults with facility code 4 means the HResult contains OLE errors (0x0 to 0x1ff) while the rest of the range (0x200 onwards) is component specific errors so 20e from one component will have a different meaning to 20e from another component.

This is why the source of the error is extra important for errors above 0x80040200.

**To Decode 0x8007nnnn Errors**

HResults with facility code 7 means the HResult contains a Windows' error code. You have to look up the Windows' error code not the HResult.

To decode 0x80070002. The 0x means it's a hexadecimal number, the 8 means error, the first 7 means it a windows error, and the rest of the number, 2, is the actual Windows error.

To look up the error we need it in decimal format. Start Calculator (Start - All Programs - Accessories - Calculator) and choose View menu - Scientific, then View menu - Hex. Enter 2. Then View menu -  Decimal. It will say 2.

Start a Command Prompt (Start - All Programs - Accessories - Command Prompt) and type

```
net helpmsg 2
```

and it will say

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

or look it up in winerror.h

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
//
// MessageText:
//
// The system cannot find the file specified.
//
#define ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND             2L
```

**Dos Error Codes (for 0x8003nnnn errors)**

Dos Error Codes (for 0x8003nnnn errors)

```
Code    Message
01  Invalid function number
02  File not found
03  Path not found
04  Too many open files (no handles left)
05  Access denied
06  Invalid handle
07  Memory control blocks destroyed
08  Insufficient memory
09  Invalid memory block address
0A  Invalid environment
0B  Invalid format
0C  Invalid access mode (open mode is invalid)
0D  Invalid data
0E  Reserved
0F  Invalid drive specified
10  Attempt to remove current directory
11  Not same device
12  No more files
13  Attempt to write on a write-protected diskette
14  Unknown unit
15  Drive not ready
16  Unknown command
17  CRC error
18  Bad request structure length
19  Seek error
1A  Unknown media type
1B  Sector not found
1C  Printer out of paper
1D  Write fault
1E  Read fault
1F  General failure
20  Sharing violation
21  Lock violation
22  Invalid disk change
23  FCB unavailable
24  Sharing buffer overflow
25  Reserved
26  Unable to complete file operation (DOS 4.x)
27-31   Reserved
32  Network request not supported
33  Remote computer not listening
34  Duplicate name on network
35  Network name not found
36  Network busy
37  Network device no longer exists
38  NetBIOS command limit exceeded
39  Network adapter error
3A  Incorrect network response
3B  Unexpected network error
3C  Incompatible remote adapter
3D  Print queue full
3E  No space for print file
3F  Print file deleted
40  Network name deleted
41  Access denied
42  Network device type incorrect
43  Network name not found
44  Network name limit exceeded
45  NetBIOS session limit exceeded
46  Temporarily paused
47  Network request not accepted
48  Print or disk redirection is paused
49-4F   Reserved
50  File already exists
51  Reserved
52  Cannot make directory entry
53  Fail on INT 24
54  Too many redirections
55  Duplicate redirection
56  Invalid password
57  Invalid parameter
58  Network device fault
59  Function not supported by network (DOS 4.x)
5A  Required system component not installed (DOS 4.x)
```

**Facility Codes**

**NTStatus Facilities**

```
Common status values    0x0
Debugger    0x1
Rpc_runtime 0x2
Rpc_stubs   0x3
Io_error_code   0x4
Various drivers 0x5-0xf
Ntwin32 0x7
Ntsspi  0x9
Terminal_server 0xa
Faciltiy_mui_error_code 0xb
Usb_error_code  0x10
Hid_error_code  0x11
Firewire_error_code 0x12
Cluster_error_code  0x13
Acpi_error_code 0x14
Sxs_error_code  0x15
Transaction 0x19
Commonlog   0x1a
Video   0x1b
Filter_manager  0x1c
Monitor 0x1d
Graphics_kernel 0x1e
Driver_framework    0x20
Fve_error_code  0x21
Fwp_error_code  0x22
Ndis_error_code 0x23
Hypervisor  0x35
Ipsec   0x36
Maximum_value   0x37
```

**HResults Facilities**

```
Null    0x0
Rpc 0x1
Dispatch    0x2
Storage 0x3
Itf 0x4
Win32   0x7
Windows 0x8
Sspi    0x9
Security    0x9
Control 0xa
Cert    0xb
Internet    0xc
Mediaserver 0xd
Msmq    0xe
Setupapi    0xf
Scard   0x10
Complus 0x11
Aaf 0x12
Urt 0x13
Acs 0x14
Dplay   0x15
Umi 0x16
Sxs 0x17
Windows_ce  0x18
Http    0x19
Usermode_commonlog  0x1a
Usermode_filter_manager 0x1f
Backgroundcopy  0x20
Configuration   0x21
State_management    0x22
Metadirectory   0x23
Windowsupdate   0x24
Directoryservice    0x25
Graphics    0x26
Shell   0x27
Tpm_services    0x28
Tpm_software    0x29
Pla 0x30
Fve 0x31
Fwp 0x32
Winrm   0x33
Ndis    0x34
Usermode_hypervisor 0x35
Cmi 0x36
Windows_defender    0x50
```

Comment: Yep, Tracing the code showed me that we had the domain in the email but not the user.  So the sender was "@abc.com" rather than "somebody@abc.com"  Thank you very much for your help and explanation.

Comment: An example of how to convert this number to a more reasonable hex error code is this :  Runtime Error    -2147217911 (dec)+4294967296 (dec)=2147749385 (dec) => 0x80040E09 (hex)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a page from Help.

```
      Exchange Server 2003
```

Error Codes  Send Feedback

: : : : : : :
CDO for Windows 2000 > Reference >
 (Declaration)

Error Codes
This section contains the custom error codes used by Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000. All of these values are available as constants in the type library CdoErrorCodes module.

Error values are 32 bit values whose structure is depicted here:

Copy Code 
   3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
  +---+-+-+-----------------------+-------------------------------+
  |Sev|C|R|     Facility          |               Code            |
  +---+-+-+-----------------------+-------------------------------+

Reading this depiction from left-to-right, the severity code, Sev, is one of the following values:

00 - Success

01 - Informational

10 - Warning

11 - Error

Followed by:

C — The customer code flag.

R — A reserved bit.

Facitlity — The facility code.

Code — The facilitiy's status code.

Error Name  Value  Remarks
CDO_E_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION
 0x80040201L
 Exception %1 was generated at address %2

CDO_E_NOT_OPENED
 0x80040202L
 No data source has been opened for the object.

CDO_E_UNSUPPORTED_DATASOURCE
 0x80040203L
 The object does not support this type of data source.

CDO_E_INVALID_PROPERTYNAME
 0x80040204L
 The object does not support the requested property name or namespace.

CDO_E_PROP_UNSUPPORTED
 0x80040205L
 The object does not support the requested property.

CDO_E_INACTIVE
 0x80040206L
 The object is not active. It may have been deleted or it may not have been opened.

CDO_E_NO_SUPPORT_FOR_OBJECTS
 0x80040207L
 The object does not support storing persistent state information for objects.

CDO_E_NOT_AVAILABLE
 0x80040208L
 The requested property or feature, while supported, is not available at this time or in this context.

CDO_E_NO_DEFAULT_DROP_DIR
 0x80040209L
 No default drop directory has been configured for this server.

CDO_E_SMTP_SERVER_REQUIRED
 0x8004020AL
 The SMTP server name is required, and was not found in the configuration source.

CDO_E_NNTP_SERVER_REQUIRED
 0x8004020BL
 The NNTP server name is required, and was not found in the configuration source.

CDO_E_RECIPIENT_MISSING
 0x8004020CL
 At least one recipient is required, but none were found.

CDO_E_FROM_MISSING
 0x8004020DL
 At least one of the From or Sender fields is required, and neither was found.

CDO_E_SENDER_REJECTED
 0x8004020EL
 The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: %1

CDO_E_RECIPIENTS_REJECTED
 0x8004020FL
 The server rejected one or more recipient addresses. The server response was: %1

CDO_E_NNTP_POST_FAILED
 0x80040210L
 The message could not be posted to the NNTP server. The transport error code was %2. The server response was %1

CDO_E_SMTP_SEND_FAILED
 0x80040211L
 The message could not be sent to the SMTP server. The transport error code was %2. The server response was %1

CDO_E_CONNECTION_DROPPED
 0x80040212L
 The transport lost its connection to the server.

CDO_E_FAILED_TO_CONNECT
 0x80040213L
 The transport failed to connect to the server.

CDO_E_INVALID_POST
 0x80040214L
 The Subject, From, and Newsgroup fields are all required, and one or more was not found.

CDO_E_AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE
 0x80040215L
 The server rejected the logon attempt due to authentication failure. The server response was: %1

CDO_E_INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE
 0x80040216L
 The content type was not valid in this context. For exmaple, the root of an MHTML message must be an HTML document.

CDO_E_LOGON_FAILURE
 0x80040217L
 The transport was unable to log on to the server.

CDO_E_HTTP_NOT_FOUND
 0x80040218L
 The requested resource could not be found. The server response was: %1.

CDO_E_HTTP_FORBIDDEN
 0x80040219L
 Access to the requested resource is denied. The server response was: %1.

CDO_E_HTTP_FAILED
 0x8004021AL
 The HTTP request failed.  The server response was: %1.

CDO_E_MULTIPART_NO_DATA
 0x8004021BL
 This is a multipart body part. It has no content other than the body parts contained within it.

CDO_E_INVALID_ENCODING_FOR_MULTIPART
 0x8004021CL
 Multipart body parts must be encoded as 7bit, 8bit, or binary.

CDO_E_PROP_NOT_FOUND
 0x8004021EL
 The requested property was not found.

CDO_E_INVALID_SEND_OPTION
 0x80040220L
 The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.

CDO_E_INVALID_POST_OPTION
 0x80040221L
 The "PostUsing" configuration value is invalid.

CDO_E_NO_PICKUP_DIR
 0x80040222L
 The pickup directory path is required and was not specified.

CDO_E_NOT_ALL_DELETED
 0x80040223L
 One or more messages could not be deleted.

CDO_E_PROP_READONLY
 0x80040227L
 The property is read-only.

CDO_E_PROP_CANNOT_DELETE
 0x80040228L
 The property cannot be deleted.

CDO_E_BAD_DATA
 0x80040229L
 Data  written to the object are inconsistent or invalid.

CDO_E_PROP_NONHEADER
 0x8004022AL
 The requested property is not in the mail header namespace.

CDO_E_INVALID_CHARSET
 0x8004022BL
 The requested character set is not installed on the computer.

CDO_E_ADOSTREAM_NOT_BOUND
 0x8004022CL
 The ADO stream has not been opened.

CDO_E_CONTENTPROPXML_NOT_FOUND
 0x8004022DL
 The content properties are missing.

CDO_E_CONTENTPROPXML_WRONG_CHARSET
 0x8004022EL
 Content properties XML must be encoded using UTF-8.

CDO_E_CONTENTPROPXML_PARSE_FAILED
 0x8004022FL
 Failed to parse content properties XML.

CDO_E_CONTENTPROPXML_CONVERT_FAILED
 0x80040230L
 Failed to convert a property from XML to a requested type.

CDO_E_NO_DIRECTORIES_SPECIFIED
 0x80040231L
 No directories were specified for resolution.

CDO_E_DIRECTORIES_UNREACHABLE
 0x80040232L
 Failed to resolve against one or more of the specified directories.

CDO_E_BAD_SENDER
 0x80040233L
 Could not find the Sender's mailbox.

CDO_E_SELF_BINDING
 0x80040234L
 Binding to self is not allowed.

CDO_E_ARGUMENT1
 0x80044000L
 The first argument is invalid.

CDO_E_ARGUMENT2
 0x80044001L
 The second argument is invalid.

CDO_E_ARGUMENT3
 0x80044002L
 The third argument is invalid.

CDO_E_ARGUMENT4
 0x80044003L
 The fourth argument is invalid.

CDO_E_ARGUMENT5
 0x80044004L
 The fifth argument is invalid.

CDO_E_NOT_FOUND
 0x800CCE05L
 The requested body part was not found in this message.

CDO_E_INVALID_ENCODING_TYPE
 0x800CCE1DL
 The content encoding type is invalid.

Documentation Feedback
Microsoft values your feedback. To rate this topic and send feedback about this topic to the documentation team, click a rating, and then click Send Feedback. For assistance with support issues, refer to the technical support information included with the product.
Poor 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 Outstanding 
To e-mail your feedback to Microsoft, click here:
© 2005 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to authenticate against your mail server. You can do this with CDOSYS by adding the following lines. You will of course need to change the sendusername and sendpassword values to a valid account.

```
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="somemail@yourserver.com"
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="yourpassword"
```