# Error Code: 80040213 Source CDO.Message.1 Failed to connect

Tags: excel, vbscript, cdo.message

This is really only my second VBS script so be gentle... I did **** out anything that was personal or company related I am sure all those fields are correct anyways.  The SMTP server is correct I double checked with the provider as that was the number 1 reason i found on other sites.  This script will also pull information from a certain cell and paste it into the body... Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Also its saying the error is on line 46 which is the "ObjSendMail.Send".  Everything works except the emailing portion...

```
    Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
StopDate = DateAdd("d", -1 - Weekday(Date), Date)
StartDate = StopDate-13

Dim xlApp
Dim xlWkb
Dim monthEnd
Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")

Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("******")
xlWkb.RunAutoMacros 1
xlApp.Run ("UpdateAll")
monthEnd = xlApp.cells(2,7).value
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strSaveFile & "Monthly Revenue Report " & Year(Now) & "." & Month(Now) & "." & Day(Now) & ".xls", 56 

xlApp.Quit
Set xlWkb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Sleep 10000
mailSubject = "Monhtly Revenue Report " & PrevMonthName
mailBody = "The Monthly Revenue Report is no ready. Month End: " & monthEnd

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 240
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "********"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "********"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

ObjSendMail.To = "*********"
ObjSendMail.Subject = mailSubject
ObjSendMail.From = "*******"
'ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "this is the body"
ObjSendMail.TextBody = mailBody
ObjSendMail.Send


'Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323.aspx). Office365 uses the submission port (587/tcp) for mail submission. Replace this:

```
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
```

with this:

```
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
```

and the error should go away (provided that outbound connections to port 587/tcp are allowed on your network).

You can test accessibility of the port with a port scanner like [nmap](http://nmap.org/), [scanline](http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/scanline.aspx), or [PortQry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310099)), or manually with `telnet`:

```
telnet smtp.office365.com 587
```

Outbound connections to port 25/tcp are most likely blocked by your provider, as a measure to prevent/reduce botnet spam.

Comment: Ok I like your answer the most... But hows this for a kicker we tested it on an old server running office 2003 with the old CDO download and it worked fine as is... What needs changed for it to work with 2007/2013?  Do the newer versions not support CDO as used in VBS?

Comment: @ELewis: Did you check if smtp.office365.com:25 is accessible from both hosts?

Comment: Just tested through telnet and got"220 sn2pr10ca0004.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL serive ready at..." Followed by datetime

Comment: Nevermind... You sir are a genius.  First telnet I did was the one you had listed so port 587 works but not 25. However on the script after I tested telnet still getting the same error -.-  Code 8004213 Source CDO.Message.1  I changed ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587

Comment: Fixed.  Sonicwall was blocking SMTP email access from all but one ipaddress port 25 did work in the end after I got the sonicwall properly configured.  Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

From [Unknown email code from CDO.Message send method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317238/unknown-email-code-from-cdo-message-send-method/24317462#24317462)

```
CDO_E_FAILED_TO_CONNECT 0x80040213L The transport failed to connect to the server.
```

If using SSL the port is normally 465.

Comment: Google says http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/settings-for-pop-and-imap-access-for-office-365-for-business-or-microsoft-exchange-accounts-HA102908389.aspx. Note Doesn't use SSL and uses port 587. But CDO doesn't do TLS. Some people claim if use set ssl to 0 and use port 25 it works (standard smtp). Let us know if it does or doesn't.

Comment: Port 465/tcp is [SMTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS), which is obsolete nowadays. Most servers use submission (port 587/tcp) instead.

Comment: Not Gmail. Which serversdo you mean, minor ones.

Comment: Port 25 works if we run it on an older version server with old outlook and CDO. I guess the issue is what needs changed so that it works on a current setup?  Looking at running it on a 2008 server running office 2013 or 2007

Comment: @phd443322: Yes, Gmail too. They do still support SMTPS for legacy clients, though.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for smtp.office365.com.  You DO indicate smtpusessl=true, but you do NOT specify the port, otherwise you get error 5.7.57.

```
    Sub SMPTTest2()
    Set emailObj = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    emailObj.From = "name@myaddress.com"
    emailObj.To = "name@youraddress.com"
    emailObj.Subject = "Test CDO"
    emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"
    'emailObj.AddAttachment "c:\windows\win.ini"

    Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration


    emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
    'Exclude the following line    
    'emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
    emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "name@myaddress.com"
    emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword"
    emailConfig.Fields.Update

    emailObj.Send

    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "Done"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Upon changing ISP's I found that CDO cannot successfully specify port 587 without causing an error.  It can only work with the default port which is 25.  Office/365 accepts port 25, but many ISP's block this port by default.  My code above gave an error when switching ISP's, then worked again when we asked the new ISP to unblock port 25.