# Classic ASP msxml3.dll error -2146697211

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

When trying to call a web service from a classic ASP (not .NET) application I'm receiving a system error I think is related to the server the web application is running on not being able to reach the server the web service is running on.

We're migrating our web services to a new server and my application could reach the old server just fine.  This is why I think it's a problem with reaching the new server.

When I extract the error number and description from the Err object I get:

```
Err.Number = -2146697211
Err.Description = System error: -2146697211
Err.Source = msxml3.dll
```

Is there a decent way of determining what this error actually means?  I'm not an expert in ASP so I don't know what many of the errors mean.  If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the defined errors.

```
DHtmled.h:#define DE_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND        0x800C0005
pstore.h:#define PST_E_TYPE_NO_EXISTS            _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x800C0005L)
UrlMon.h:#define INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND        _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x800C0005L)
```

They all seem to be internet thing doesn't exist.

See my post here on how to decode errors [Unknown email code from CDO.Message send method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317238/unknown-email-code-from-cdo-message-send-method) (and there is a new paragraph not on that page reproduced below)

**To Decode 0x8019nnnn Errors**

HResults with facility 0x19 are HTTP errors. Codes under 16,384 (0x4000) are the same as HTTP errors, eg HTTP status 404: The requested URL does not exist on the server is 0x80190194 (0x194 = 404). Codes 16,384 and higher are BITS specific.

Answer (score 1):

This uses xml lib. If you are actually connecting to a server, this also gets the server response.

The URL has to be 100% correct. Unlike a browser there is no code to fix urls.

The purpose of my program is to get error details.

How I get a correct URL is to type my url in a browser, navigate, and the correct URL is often in the address bar. The other way is to use Properties of a link etc to get the URL.

Also Microsoft.XMLHTTP maps to Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP maps to Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0. Try a later one

Try this way using xmlhttp. Edit the url's etc. If it seems to work comment out the if / end if to dump info even if seeming to work. It's vbscript but vbscript works in vb6.

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2
```

Also see if these other objects work.

```
C:\Users>reg query hkcr /f xmlhttp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0
End of search: 12 match(es) found.
```

### Also be aware there is a limit on how many times you can call any particular XMLHTTP object before a lockout occurs. If that happens, and it does when debugging code, just change to a different xmlhttp object